# Different behavior of the operator ^ in PHP and Perl

Tags: php, perl

I ported script from Perl to PHP and I have errors. The following code returns a different result for the same input data. Rather string is returned to Perl 2 times longer than the line in PHP, but the beginning of this line coincides with the line of PHP.
I expect that it encoded input lines, but I can not figure out until the end.

```
$test = $password ^ $newchal;
```

Please, help me to get the same value of `$test` in PHP as in Perl?

Comment: Are both variables strings?

Comment: Yes! Both variables is strings.

Comment: What is the **exact** output of: `var_dump($password);` and `var_dump($newchal);` ?

Comment: `string(8) "password" string(16) "Т®“LU)dЮ·ЃqцJ€"`

Comment: It is logical that the line is shorter by 2 times as `$password` length 8. I tried to convert it to UTF-16, but then the result of bitwise another.

Answer (score 4):

The defined behavior of the languages appears to be different.

[For Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> If the operands to a binary bitwise op are strings of different sizes,
>   | and ^ ops act as though the shorter operand had additional zero bits
>   on the right

The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) doesn't seem to define what happens in this case, but one of the examples gives it away:

```
echo "12" ^ "9"; // Outputs the Backspace character (ascii 8)
                 // ('1' (ascii 49)) ^ ('9' (ascii 57)) = #8
```

So it appears that in PHP, the extra characters in the longer string will just be discarded, while in Perl they will be included.

**Update:**

To get the desired behavior in PHP, there are a couple of options.  You could add null characters to the end of the string.

```
$password = '        ';
$newchal = "abcdefghijklmnop";

#prints ABCDEFGH
echo $password ^ $newchal;

$password .= "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";

#prints ABCDEFGHijklmnop
echo $password ^ $newchal;
```

This example assumes the strings are always a fixed, known length.  If you need to handle arbitrary cases, you could measure the length of each string and then add null characters as necessary. And of course, if you don't want to alter the original variable, put it in a temporary variable before doing the above.

Comment: Oh, how i can add zero bits to shortest value in PHP for same begavior?

Answer (score 0):

Right answer (if we know, that password no longer $newchal)

```
$iterations = ceil(mb_strlen($newchal) / mb_strlen($password)) - 1;
  while($iterations > 0){
      $password .= ($password ^ $password);
     $iterations--;
  }
 $code = $password ^ $newchal;
```